# Using DOS to copy specific data

Tags: xml, windows, csv, cmd

I need to copy specific data from xml file to a csv format file via dos batch file.

From a large xml (900Mb) file, collect variable lenght data from the following Tags;

```
<Object Id="_1_100" Name="DATA THAT I NEED" ObjectType="Trial">
<L>DATA I NEED</L>
<A>DATA I NEED</A>
<BL>DATA I NEED</B>
<Tag Name="TargetLab" Value="DATA I NEED,DATA I NEED,DATA I NEED" />
```

The Object ID "name" is present multiple times, so each "name" and cooresponding data must remain together.

Comment: Are you forced to do it via batch? I'm not a master in batch but I know that what you're asking is quite difficult. Can't you use a scripting language or something compiled?

Comment: I am NOT familiar with scripting language or compiling...

Comment: In reading other posts the major issues seem to be the < > characters...I could remove those using a series of find/replace so that <L> would wind up being something like LLL and all <> would be eliminated...

Comment: What about working on the XML in Excel ? It should allow you to manipulate the data in a way you could use (not an expert, just a random idea)

Comment: I'd take a look at regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I can do it via Excel, but I am forced to break the XML file into smaller sections, sort/copy/paste/save in csv...then try tro reassemble the smaller sections into 1 file...looking for something a little less time consuming...

Comment: "I only know how to use a hammer, so please tell me how I can use it to fix my computer." Trying to use a batch file for this is simply the wrong approach, and rather than attempting to do it anyway you should be attempting to learn to use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built-in tools that would allow you to process Xml in a batch file. However you could do one of the following:

- use PowerShell instead of batch - PowerShell has commands that let you process Xml files
- download [msxsl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) which will allow you to use xslt in your .bat file. Writing an xslt that converts xml to csv should not be difficult
- I think you could also use cscript/wscript which should allow you to create the msxml object and then again you could create an Xslt to convert xml to csv or you could possibly to the same using DOM interface